# Fetching document that has labels in array

Tags: mongodb

I have the following collection on Atlas running MongoDB 4.2.2 Enterprise:

```js
{
    "items": [
        {
            "pID": 1111,
            "name": "Test Item #1111",
            "amount": 11,
            "labels": [
                "test",
                "testcat1"
            ]
        },
        {
            "pID": 2222,
            "name": "Test Item #2222",
            "amount": 22,
            "labels": [
                "test",
                "testcat2"
            ]
        },
        {
            "pID": 3333,
            "name": "Test Item #3333",
            "amount": 33,
            "labels": [
                "test",
                "testcat3"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

My objective is to fetch **all** the products matching a set of labels. For example, the idea is that I can search for `["test"]` and get all 3 items, but `["test", "testcat1"]` should only return the first one.

Searching on the internet I see people have suggested using `db.inventories.find( { "_id" : 72986, "items.labels" : { $all : ["test", "testcat2"] } } )`, but I get back the whole array, not just the matching item:

```js
[
    {
        "pID": 1111,
        "name": "Test Item #1111",
        "amount": 11,
        "labels": [
            "test",
            "testcat1"
        ]
    },
    {
        "pID": 2222,
        "name": "Test Item #2222",
        "amount": 22,
        "labels": [
            "test",
            "testcat2"
        ]
    },
    {
        "pID": 3333,
        "name": "Test Item #3333",
        "amount": 33,
        "labels": [
            "tets",
            "testcat3"
        ]
    }
]
```

When I try the projection `{"items.$" : 1}` I'm getting the correct item, but just one. I need a similar behavior that can fetch multiple items.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It would be helpful if you format your example document to make it easier to understand.  Your example shows a single document with a field called 'items' with an array of sub documents having a field 'labels' with an array of scalar strings.  This is not evident with the current formatting.  Since you only have a single document in your example the find can only return a single document, or no document.  I presume your real world problem has more than one document.  You should include some of those examples too.  I presume pID 3333 label 'tets' is a typo?  If not, you should clarify.

Comment: @barrypicker Yes, it was a typo, now fixed. Thanks. The real-world application does in fact have more than one document, but the question asks about accessing a value inside this document and not about finding said value in multiple documents.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem with using [$elemMatch](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/projection/elemMatch/index.html) or [$](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/projection/positional/) is they'll only return first matched document - would be problematic if `items.labels` has multiple matching items objects to passed in input, You can try below query :

```
db.collection.aggregate([{
    $addFields: {
        'items': {
            $filter: {
                input: "$items",
                as: "item",
                cond: { $setIsSubset: [['test',"testcat1"], "$$item.labels"] }
            }
        }
    }
}])
```

**Test :** [MongoDB-Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/cjZPo2HDx-b)

**Ref :** [$setIsSubset](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/setIsSubset/#example)

If passed in array `['test',"testcat1"]` is not a subset of `item.labels` then for those documents response would be

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5e3332078bbf43c5c046e5e2"),
    "items" : []
}
```

So you might need to have a `$match` stage after `$addFields` to remove those docs. In another way you can have `$match` as first stage to limit no.of docs to `$addFields` stage :

```
{
    $match: {
        "items.labels": {
            $all: // or can be $in
            [
            [ "test", "testcat1" ]
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Then the above stage will remove docs where field `items.labels` doesn't have `["test","testcat1"]`.

Comment: Thank you very much, kind person! Works as asked. As far as I can tell the second part of your solution does not make a difference (will test more), but funny enough it helped me solve another problem I was having

Comment: @CamiloHernández : Test by adding `$match` as first stage & `$addFields` as second stage in mongo playground link !! For `$match` you pass this array `["testXYZ", "testcat1XYZ"]` you'll see the difference :-)